# $cordovaSQLite.execute is not a function in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my code **$cordovaSQLite.execute** function works good in **.run**  function but gives me error in my controller . I don't know what i am doing wrong , i have included all the required plugin and follow step of this very good example
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/

```
 var db = null;
    var myapp=angular.module('starter', ['ionic','btford.socket-io','LoginCntrl','SlideCntrl','app','ChatCntrl','ngCordova','ngCordova.plugins.sqlite'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform,$cordovaSQLite) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
        console.log("The application is resuming from the background");
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: App_DB_Name });
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");

        var query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM people WHERE lastname = ?";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, ["pruthvi"]).then(function(result) {
            if(result.rows.length > 0) {
                console.log("SELECTED -> " + result.rows.item(0).firstname + " " + result.rows.item(0).lastname);
                alert("SELECTED -> "+ result.rows.item(0).firstname + " " + result.rows.item(0).lastname)
            } else {
                console.log("No results found");
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
        //  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ App_DB_Table_Login_Name +"(id integer primary key, login_username text, login_password text)");
        console.log("success");
    });
});


myapp.controller('IndexController', ['$scope','$rootScope', function($scope,$rootScope,$cordovaSQLite, $ionicPlatform){
    var query = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM people WHERE lastname = ?";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, ["pruthvi"]).then(function(result) {
        if(result.rows.length > 0) {
            console.log("SELECTED -> " + result.rows.item(0).firstname + " " + result.rows.item(0).lastname);
            alert("SELECTED -> "+ result.rows.item(0).firstname + " " + result.rows.item(0).lastname)
        } else {
            console.log("No results found");
        }
    }, function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}]);
```

> TypeError: $cordovaSQLite.execute is not a function
>       at new  (app.js:105)
>       at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:13277)
>       at extend.instance (ionic.bundle.js:17826)
>       at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:16936)
>       at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:16368)
>       at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:16372)
>       at publicLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:16243)
>       at ionic.bundle.js:10462
>       at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:24673)
>       at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:24772)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21157 console-via-logger.js:173 No
>   Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the
>   cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.(anonymous function) @
>   console-via-logger.js:173 console-via-logger.js:173 The application is
>   resuming from the background console-via-logger.js:173 OPEN database:
>   db_demoionic.db 2console-via-logger.js:173 new transaction is waiting
>   for open operation console-via-logger.js:173 success
>   console-via-logger.js:173 DB opened: db_demoionic.db
>   console-via-logger.js:173 No results found console-via-logger.js:173
>   No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using
>   the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin. 3console-via-logger.js:173 No
>   Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the
>   cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code in your `myapp.controller(...)` call is executed upon startup. If the controller is connected to something like a page body it also has to wait until the Ionic/ngCordova is ready (using `$ionicPlatform.ready(...)` for example).